# How to create a signup modal with Laravel Framework?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, authentication, laravel-routing

I have a modal in my layout to create users (as the Signup option), I can correctly create the user, but I need to log it in automatically  and also redirect him to another page, how can I do it?

Here's my code:

My modal in the header layout

```
<div id="LoginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/Login/Email_Gate.png);width: 420px;height: 550px;">
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:0;">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="LoginNavUl" style="margin:50px;">
                        <li style="width: 150px;margin: 0; height: 47px;"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" style="text-align: center;">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li class="active" style="width: 150px;margin: 0;"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" style="text-align: center;">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content active">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                            <div class="green-banner" style="background-color: #04c08d; height: 60px;">
                                <p>Nice to meet you.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-login" style="padding-left:70px; padding-right:70px; padding-top:50px;">
                                <form id="formRegister" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('signup') }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Email"><br/>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Password"><br/>
                                    <input type="date" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 70px;" name ="eventdate" placeholder="Event Date"/><br/>
                                    <div class="btn-submit-login">
                                        <div>
                                            <button id="edit-submit" name="op"  type="submit" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;">SIGN UP</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public function createUser(Request $request )                        
{                                                                         
$email = $request['email'];                                           
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);                             

$user = new UserModel();                                              
$user->email = $email;                                                
$user->password = $password;                                          
$user->role_id = 3;                                                   
$user->save();                                                        

/*
 I need to log the user here 
*/

if  user is logged in {    
    Redirect::to('/collection');                                      
} else {                                                              
    Redirect::to('/');                                                
}
```

}

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can login the user and redirect him by adding these two lines of code right after you had saved your user in in your `createUser` function:

```
Auth::login($user);

Redirect::to('/collection');
```

Comment: For this, make sure the user model uses `Authenticatable`. OP seems to use his own user model

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work in your controller:

```
public function createUser(Request $request )                        
{                                                                         
$email = $request['email'];                                           
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);                             

$user = new UserModel();                                              
$user->email = $email;                                                
$user->password = $password;                                          
$user->role_id = 3;                                                   
$user->save();

if  ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]) ) {    
    Redirect::to('/collection');                                      
} else {                                                              
    Redirect::to('/');                                                
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Laravel's built in Authentication?

In `Laravel 5.3` you should see a class called `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`

This controller uses a trait called `RegistersUser` by default. This class does exactly what you would think. It registers a user.
You can override any of the trait methods in your `RegisterController.php` class to add whatever functionality you want.

You also have a `LoginController.php` which logs in a user, and it even provides a method called `authenticated()` that you can override in your `LoginController.php` to do all sorts of stuff *after* a user has been authenticated.

As a sidenote, I'm not sure you quite understand the "point" of laravel, or what it actually have to offer. Do you really need to create your own `UserModel`? It comes built in with a user model that is built to work seamlessly with the rest of the framework - especially the login/register classes. When it's so easy to extend and customize every aspect of so much in laravel, I don't see why you are reinventing the wheel for so much.

My suggestion is to take a look at the documentation @ https://laravel.com/docs/

See what laravel has to offer, and try to use it. You are after all using Laravel. If you're not going to utilize what Laravel has to offer, you would probably be better off pulling in Eloquent etc. through composer without having the added weight of Laravel.